# Why will this code not create an Opportunity using Odata in Microsoft Dynamics CRM 2011?

Tags: javascript, dynamics-crm-2011

Long story short, this code WILL create an Account when I change the URL ending to "AccountSet" but it WILL NOT do anything but give me a "Bad Request" error when I try creating a new Opportunity. Does anybody see something I am missing? Thank you so much for any help here. (Also, for the record, I did try CRMRestkit and got an error there too).

```
var newOpportunity = new Object();

newOpportunity.Name = "TEST";
newOpportunity.StatusCode = 0;

var contact = new Object();
contact.Id = "b4531ee9-9477-4262-8e18-00b60369352a";
contact.LogicalName = "contact";
contact.Name = "Bacon Jones";

newOpportunity.ContactId = contact;

var jsonNewOpp = window.JSON.stringify(newOpportunity);

$.ajax({ type: "POST",
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    datatype: "json",
    url: Xrm.Page.context.getServerUrl() + "/XRMServices/2011/OrganizationData.svc/OpportunitySet",
    data: jsonNewOpp,
    beforeSend: function (XMLHttpRequest) {
        XMLHttpRequest.setRequestHeader("Accept", "application/json");
    },
    success: function (data, textStatus, XmlHttpRequest) {
        alert("success");
        //var getNewRecord = data["d"];
        //alert("GUID: " + getNewRecord.OpportunityId);
    },
    error: function (XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {
        alert("failure due to " + errorThrown);
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried running Fiddler to receive a better error message?

The code looks fine, maybe the error is in the field names?

Is the REST endpoint throwing the same error?

Thanks,

Mario

Comment: You can see if turning on tracing (https://crmdiagtool2011.codeplex.com/) will give you a better error as well.

Comment: Hmm, is there a quick tutorial on how to run Fiddler to get that message? :) I'm sorry, I have only used it once a long time ago.

Comment: Just install it and open it, it should record all your traffic.
You will see a long list will all the calls, identify yours and have a look at the TextView and RawView of the BadRequest response

Comment: I get this message from TextView

Comment: {
    "error": {
    "code": "-2147220947", "message": {
    "lang": "en-US", "value": "Customer not specified."
    }
    }
    }

Comment: YOU'RE AMAZING! OUTSTANDING! COMMANDING! (alright enough lyrics from "Whoomp! There it is!" You totally saved me here man and I cannot thank you enough. I am new to this site in practice so if I did not vote your answer up accurately let me know as I totally owe you!!!